# I get "InvalidSignatureException: Signature expired" when Lambda is invoked

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have the following architecture:

`S3 ---> S3 Notification ---> SQS ---> Lambda`

Sometimes, I'm getting the following error message from the Lambda (of course the times are different):

```
"errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection" 
"errorMessage": "InvalidSignatureException: Signature expired: 20221230T132433Z is now earlier than 20221230T132603Z (20221230T133103Z - 5 min.)"
```

I have a retry policy in the SQS, so when the error occurs, the message returns to the SQS, and the Lambda process it again. When it processes it again, the same message, it succeeds and is processed successfully.

Any idea why?

Comment: From the looks of it, you're taking too long to send a request to lambda after creating the request. How are you invoking Lambda?

Comment: @ZackNewsham I’m invoking the Lambda through SQS.

Comment: Do you have any timestamps for when these events occur, specifically when SQS ingests, when Lambda is triggered, when Lambda starts up, then the same for the retry? My suspicion here is it takes longer than 5 minutes for your lambda job to cold start (possible if you're downloading large binaries, or do a lot of init work) on retry, the lambda is already started so there is no init time and it succeeds

Comment: @ZackNewsham It does not happen during a cold start. For example one of the invocations:
The file was uploaded to S3 in 21:19 and the Lambda was triggered with this file in 21:19, so it is not that.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a very specific use case, but I hope the background research and solutions is helpful:

My team was seeing the same sporadic error message. We isolated the code and found our aws-sdk secrets calls in the lambda appeared to be the culprit. It started when we switched from the full aws-sdk v2 package to aws-sdk v3 libraries, e.g. @aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager. We also have provisioned concurrency enabled and ruled out cold starts.

**Solution #1**: Revert back to using the full aws-sdk v2. This is pretty short term as AWS will sunset v2 at some point in the near future.

**Solution #2**: This thread comment talks about the nodeJS async init problem and how it may be related to the initial call to the handler in a lambda instance. The poster's solution is just to call the lambda every 4 minutes:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/4429#issuecomment-1451074059

**Solution #3**: Rather than do this, we are now using the secrets lambda extension as a layer to take advantage of secrets caching:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-the-aws-parameter-and-secrets-lambda-extension-to-cache-parameters-and-secrets/